# formidable: node.js files object is null

Tags: node.js, formidable

Following is a basic example of file upload using formidable in node.js
Upon selecting a file, the 'files' object in the node.js side is empty.
Can you please tell what is wrong in my code ?

```js
  /********************************TS Angular component **************************/
  public handleFileInput (event) 
  {
    //open select file dialog
    console.log (event.target.files[0]);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("thumbnail", event.target.files[0]);

    this.http.post (TGT_IP+'/fileupload',formData, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).subscribe(
      (val) => {
          console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", 
                      val);
      },
      response => {
          console.log("POST call in error", response);
      },
      () => {
          console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
      }); 
  }
  
/**************************** node.js **************************/
const Net = require('net');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var http=require ('http');

http.createServer (function(req,res) {
    
        const form = formidable({});

        form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
              console.log (files);
});
}).listen (8000);
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filetoupload" (change)="handleFileInput($event)"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: Why don't you use the [example code](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable#with-nodejs-http-module) for handling the incoming data?

Comment: You are right !  I got 'err'. What is the reason for this error ?

Comment: You're not using the example code, at least your question isn't showing that you do. I don't know why you're reading `data` events on `req`, but that's breaking `formidable`.

Comment: Right again. Thank you very much ! I fixed the node.js code in the question. Now 'files' object is right. I really appreciate your help.